# How to access a value in a array

Tags: p5.js

I need to access the wall array inside the C variable. I can find what c is, but not what any specific value of c. I probably made a mistake of how to access the value from this array, but I tried to do c[3], and it always says undefined. This is the full program link https://editor.p5js.org/Meowmeow/sketches/b4AhGA4xH.

```
function index(i, j) {

  if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols - 1 || j > cols - 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  return i + j * cols
}

function Cell(i, j) {


  this.visited = false;
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
  this.checkNeighbors = function() {
    var neighbors = []
    var top = grid[index(i, j - 1)]
    var right = grid[index(i + 1, j)]
    var left = grid[index(i - 1, j)]
    var bottom = grid[index(i, j + 1)]
    var Wall = this.walls;
    
    var wall=[]
    wall.push(i,j,Wall)
    
    
    if (top && !top.visited) {
      neighbors.push(top);
    }

    if (right && !right.visited) {
      neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if (bottom && !bottom.visited) {
      neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if (left && !left.visited) {
      neighbors.push(left);
    }

    if (neighbors.length > 0) {
      var r = floor(random(0, neighbors.length))
      return neighbors[r];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }

  }

  this.highlight = function() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 255, 100)
    rect(x, y, w, w);

  }
  this.show = function() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    stroke(255);
    noFill();

    if (this.walls[0]) {
      line(x, y, x + w, y);
    }
    if (this.walls[1]) {
      line(x + w, y, x + w, y + w);
    }

    if (this.walls[2]) {
      line(x + w, y + w, x, y + w);
    }
    if (this.walls[3]) {
      line(x, y + w, x, y);
    }

    if (this.visited) {
      fill(255, 0, 255, 100);
      noStroke();
      rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
  }
};






function removeWalls(a, b) {
  var x = a.i - b.i;
  if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false;
  } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
  }
  var y = a.j - b.j;

  if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false;
  } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
  }


}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].show()
  }


  //Step One
  current.visited = true;
  current.highlight();

  var next = current.checkNeighbors()
  if (next) {
    next.visited = true;

    //Step 2
    stack.push(current);
    check.push(current)

    //Step 3
    removeWalls(current, next) 
    {}


    //Step 4 
    current = next;
  } else if (stack.length > 0) {
    current = stack.pop();

  }


  if (stack[0] === undefined) {
    fill(0, 105, 100)
    rect(0, 0, w, w)
    rect(width - w, height - w, w, w)
    frameRate(8)
  
    
    var c = check.find(cell => cell.i == ~~(k/w) && cell.j == ~~(m/w));
      

    console.log(c)
    if(c===undefined)
```

I'm not sure if I needed to put in this much of the code, but I didn't want to leave anything important out.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track.

I would just finish that check to see if a cell has been found before attempting to access the `walls` property. For example:

```
if(c===undefined){
   console.log('no cell found');
}else{
   console.log('i',c.i,'j', c.j,'walls', c.walls);
}
```

as you press the arrow keys you should see different cell row/col indices and `walls`.